# webbrowser modules only opens url in mozilla?

Tags: python

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url)
```

I am using this to open url in browser. But it opens only in `'Mozilla'` why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open).  It uses the default browser.  Look at [`webbrowser.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get) for instructions on using a different browser.